# RECENT BLOCKS RECENT TRANSACTION

Tags: transactions

[image]

How I can do this with local Blockchain, I would like to have the RECENT TRANSACTIONS and RECENT BLOCKS.

I use these two APIs:

http://host/:port/v1/history/get_transaction

http://localhost:8080/v1/chain/get_block

but it will return a single record, however I would like to have 10 records.

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking for. Can you add/modify the description to give us a better understanding?

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question.